# Playing Video On Hover, Hiding Video On Mouseout Won't Restart & Show Video

Tags: jquery

I'm making a gallery and I have some video thumbnails that play on hover and are supposed to go back to the background on mouseout. It seems to be working just fine, but I ran into a problem getting the video to play again when I mouseenter again. Any tips? Here's the code I was using:

```
var figure = $(".video").mouseenter( hoverVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
$('video', this).get(0).play().show(); 
}
var figure = $(".video").mouseleave( hideVideo );
function hideVideo(e) {
$('video', this).load().hide(); 
}
```

Comment: why `hide()` you should pause it or stop it

Comment: I have a background that I want it to return to on mouseout. Would pausing it and stopping it didn't seem to do that.

Comment: please share a fiddle for this

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this code

```js
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).load(); 
}
```

```css
#videosList {
 max-width: 600px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video {
  background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/nZcejtAwxz4/maxresdefault.jpg');
  height: 330px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Hide Play button + controls on iOS */
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="videosList">           

<div class="video">
    <video class="thevideo" loop preload="none">
      <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
  Hover mouse over video. Desktop only [ Obviously! ;) ]
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmmm... pausing doesn't look terrible, but it doesn't seem to be hiding it. I added hide() and pause() but it just stays paused, doesn't hide.

Comment: update the snippet, when mouse out, load function call.